# Deploying Rails with ActionCable to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using ALB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, actioncable

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 5.1.4 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and cannot get ActionCable to work. There appears to be a problem with upgrading the HTTP connection to a WebSocket, as per the Rails logs:

```
I, [2017-11-29T20:53:23.533734 #6275]  INFO -- : [014bad33-65a1-489e-9108-dc4157965491] Started GET "/cable" for 24.192.57.23 at 2017-11-29 20:53:23 +0000
I, [2017-11-29T20:53:23.534481 #6275]  INFO -- : [014bad33-65a1-489e-9108-dc4157965491] Started GET "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 24.192.57.23 at 2017-11-29 20:53:23 +0000
E, [2017-11-29T20:53:23.534582 #6275] ERROR -- : [014bad33-65a1-489e-9108-dc4157965491] Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
I, [2017-11-29T20:53:23.534721 #6275]  INFO -- : [014bad33-65a1-489e-9108-dc4157965491] Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 24.192.57.23 at 2017-11-29 20:53:23 +0000
```

The Elastic Beanstalk configuration uses an ALB (not an ELB) which is supposed to work with WebSockets out-of-the-box.

I've tried using an ELB with TCP instead of HTTP, [configuring nginx reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536926/actioncable-on-aws-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code) , and [modifying application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45462800/actioncable-on-production-error-during-websocket-handshake-unexpected-response?rq=1) all without success. There seems to be consensus around the reverse proxy but I can't seem to get the incantation correct.

Please help!

Comment: Using a combination of the reverse proxy and the modification of application settings, the WebSocket connection is now being upgraded.

Comment: can you provide some code as an example? I'm having the same issue right now

Comment: @JuanFuentes i used the same answer as this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34693689/3439190) but updated the server_name to mine (i.e. create .ebextensions/nginx_proxy.conf file with the contents as per the answer) and then i used the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45463858/3439190) to update my environment config files (i.e. updated config/environments/production.rb with the code in the answer and with my server's host name). does that help?

Comment: This worked for me using Rails 7 and puma 6
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77590435/3693398