# Rails 5 ActionCable fails to upgrade to WebSocket on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, websocket

For context, I've already tried to implement many answers regarding nginx (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561776/deploying-rails-with-actioncable-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-alb)) to no success.  This appears to be an issue related to nginx that isn't explored in other answers.

---

Using Rails 5.2 and Docker on a multicontainer EBS, WebSocket connections are failing.  This failure only occurs when deployed and the same configuration works as expected locally.

*I am using the Postgres adaptor with ActionCable*

### Problem Description:

My website is deployed to EBS and displays information just fine.  My Postgres instance is connected and working as expected. However, these errors occur on WebSocket enabled pages:

**In browser:**

When I go to my SSL enabled site, a notice appears in the JS console:

```
The connection to wss://redacted.com/cable was interrupted while the page was loading.
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://redacted.com/cable.
```

(This message repeats every ~5s)

**Rails server logs:**

```
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, HTTP_UPGRADE: )
Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for <redacted IP> at 2018-02-28 02:49:03 +0000
```

(This message repeats every ~5s)

---

### Prior research

**Error codes:**

Others in this situation note that their console throws a `400 - Bad handshake` error (or similar).  This is not the case here.

**nginx (important):**

As well, others seem to think that nginx is to blame.  However, *I cannot access nginx within my EBS instance*.  Any call for nginx results in `service nginx not found` and any modification of an nginx file via `.ebextensions` fails.

It's worth noting that I have no nginx Docker image or configuration whatsoever.  I'm trying to modify EBS' built-in nginx configuration.  To get to this point (where my website loads but WebSockets don't work), I have not configured nginx at all.

---

### Troubleshooting steps taken

- Changed EBS load balancer from HTTP to TCP
- Modification of nginx (see above)
- Specifying the ActionCable server URL in my `production.rb`
- Specifying allowed WebSocket hosts in `production.rb`
- Changing `cable.yml` adapters and hosts

Comment: It sounds like you are using a Classic ELB, rather than an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html).  Check this?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That seems to have done it!  Thank you so much!  If you make this into an answer, I'll vote it as winner